# codeigniter echo of session data doubles itself

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am storing random stuff in my CI session such as a userID for example, and I have crawled up and down my code looking for the error, to then end up doing the sane thing and doing a `var_dump` / `print_r` on my session data.

So heres the thing. I do the print_r and i see the userID correctly in this case 21. But if I go one line directly below that print_r and do `echo $this->session->userdata('userID');` my result is 2121 instead of 21, which is messing things all sorts of up for me, and I can't find anything anywhere that mentions a similar problem so I am hoping someone here can set me straight.

***edit to show "code"***

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
echo $this->session->userdata('userID');
```

which yields this result...

```
Array ( [userID] => 21 ) 21
```

but if I do this..

```
//print_r($this->session->userdata);
echo $this->session->userdata('userID');
```

i get this as a result

```
2121
```

hopefully this clears up the confusion some..

Comment: please post your whole code - because what you have just describe SHOULD print 2121 (print_r() followed by echo() ) - what is the problem?

Comment: edited post, hopefully that clears up the misunderstanding..

Comment: The misunderstanding is on your side chris. PHP does what you have told it to do, the output in that form is correct. So you probably should consider re-phrasing your question. What do you want ot know?

Comment: how is the output supposed to be 2121? where am I telling it to add the second 21 in here? When in the session data its just 21 one would expect to see 21 when they echo out a specific object from an array would they not? This is the confusion I suppose I have

Comment: what is the output if you replace $this->session->userdata('userID'); by $this->session->userdata['userID']; ?

Comment: and try this - and tell us what your output is? echo "start"; $this->session->userdata('userID'); echo "end";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you're outputting 21 someplace else
which is why you get `2121` and `Array ( [userID] => 21 ) 21`
do an `exit()`;
right after `echo $this->session->userdata('userID');`
and you'll see exactly what is stored there,
also `var_dump()` is a good idea.

Comment: ironically enough, this works.. but the kicker is.. I comment out the loan echo I have for that in the controller, like the controller is just that of which I put above. the single print_r and the single echo. thats it while im trying to debunk this.. anyway.. I comment out that one echo, theres nothing.. I put exit after that one echo and I get just whats expected